# Error with axios: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript, axios

Ok, I have an interceptors in my `index.js` to refresh the token if the status code is `401`, this works fine, but in login page if I return another status code from the server, the messages errors in the page not working, because the `axios` interceptors not receive a `401`.

But if receive a `401`, the interceptors work fine.

This is a screenshot about that. It returns a `404` from the server if not found the user.
[image]

The error is related with `Login.vue`, but if I delete the `axios.interceptors` in my `index.js` the "status" in `Login.vue` it works fine.

**Interceptors**

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response;
}, error => {
  if (error.response.status === undefined) {
    return;
  } else {
    const code = error.response.status;
    if (code === 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      axios.get("token/refresh", {
        params: {
          correo: window.localStorage.getItem("email")
        }
      }).then(response => {
        var refresh_token = response.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem("token", refresh_token);
      }).catch(error => {
        const response = error.response;
        console.log(response.data.errors);
      })
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
});
```

I tried in the interceptors, to use something like this:

```
if(error.response.status == undefined) return;
```

But it doesn't work.

**Login Catch**

```
          .catch(error => {
        this.loading = false;
        if (error.response.status != null) {
          switch (error.response.status) {
            case 400:
              this.alertError = true;
              this.errorMessage = "No estás autorizado para acceder.";
              this.loading = false;
              break;
            case 500:
              this.alertError = true;
              this.errorMessage =
                "Hay un problema con el servidor, disculpa las molestias.";
              this.loading = false;
              break;
            case 404:
              this.alertError = true;
              this.errorMessage = "Vuelve a ingresar tu contraseña";
              break;
            default:
              this.alertError = true;
              this.errorMessage =
                "Hay un error interno en el servidor, intenta de nuevo más tarde";
          }
        }
      })
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried logging the `error` variable to find out what properties it contains?  (Off the top of my head I think you probably want `error.status` not `error.response.status`, but it'd be easier to check than to guess.)

Comment: @DanielBeck error.status not works, error.response contains all: data, status, headers, reques, config...

Comment: @IsaíasOrozcoToledo is the problem solved?

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan yes

Answer (score 3):

A response interceptor **must** return a response, a resolved promise or a rejected promise.

Your interceptor has logic paths that don't return anything, hence your problem.

You want something like this...

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (r) => r,
  (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      // make sure to return the new promise
      return axios
        .get("token/refresh", {
          params: {
            correo: window.localStorage.getItem("email"),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
          // now replay the original request
          return axios.request(error.config);
        });
    }
    // not a 401, simply fail the response
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

From your implementation, you are trying to refresh the token. What you can do is to shift the refresh token handling to the server side. So If the token expires the server will send the token in the header and inside the `axios interceptors` write a code as follows to update the local storage when the header contains auth token. 
Below a sample implementation from my side project

```
export default () => {
const authTokenJson = localStorage.getItem('auth');

let axiosInstance = null;

if (authTokenJson) {
    const tokens = JSON.parse(authTokenJson);
    axiosInstance = axios.create({
        headers: {
            'authorization': `Bearer ${tokens.token}`,
            'refresh-token': `${tokens.refreshToken}`
        }
    });
} else {
    axiosInstance = axios.create();
}

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        console.log(response);
        const tokens = {
            token: response.headers['authorization'],
            refreshToken: response.headers['refresh-token']
        };
        if (tokens.token && tokens.refreshToken) {
            setTokens(JSON.stringify(tokens));
        }
        return response;
    },
    err => {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
            EventBus.$emit('errors:401');
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);
return axiosInstance;
};
```