# Refreshing token on axios and retry

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i want to catch 401 errors in axios, refreshing api token and then resolve the response of a axios call with new access_token.

Problem im facings is the the response from axios interceptor fires after catch handler from original request.

```js
getCurrentPlaying = async () => {
    let config = {
      method: 'get',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.user.spotify_access_token}`
      }
    }

    axios.request(config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // This fires first
        console.log('getCurrentPlaying', error.response.data)
      })
  }
```

and my interceptor

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
      const status = error.response ? error.response.status : null

      if (status === 401) {
        const refreshConfig = {
          method: 'post',
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(this.clientId + ':' + this.clientSecret).toString('base64'))
          },
          data: new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: this.user.spotify_refresh_token,
            client_id: this.clientId
          }),
        }

        axios.request(refreshConfig)
          .then((response) => {
            this.user.spotify_access_token = response.data.access_token
            this.user.save().then(() => {
              // This fires second
              console.log('Access token refreshed')
              error.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token

              // This fires third
              console.log('Retrying request')
              return axios(error.config)
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error)
          })
      }

      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
```

Comment: The 'currently-playing' API needs the `Access User Resources`, Your get token Client credentials flow ( by client ID & client secret) can't get call 'currently-playing' API. So you need change from "Client Credentials Flow" to "Authorization code Flow". see detail in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization) at "Which OAuth flow should I use?" section.

Comment: You need a `return` before `axios.request()`. You can also remove the `.catch()`, it's redundant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71933098/283366) which is more specific to Axios interceptors